# Select 1 random item in MySQL from many post_ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database which is laid out like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [post_id] => 9480
            [title] => This is numero uno
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [post_id] => 9480
            [title] => I like food
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [post_id] => 9480
            [title] => Oranges!
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [post_id] => 9476
            [title] => The quick brown fox
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [post_id] => 9476
            [title] => jumped!
        )

)
```

Note that `post_id` can the same on some rows. This is basically several headline variations belonging to a single post.

What I want to do is choose ONE headline at random using MySQL when given an array of ID's for `post_id`

So the output might be something like this (from the input above):

```
9480 - 25 - I like food
9476 - 28 - The quick brown fox
```

where each of those are selected at random from the subset of `post_id`s.

This is what I had so far... not much :/

```
SELECT `id`, `post_id`, `title` FROM `headlines` WHERE `post_id` IN(9480,9476)
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` in combination with `ORDER BY RAND()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order by rand() and then limit 1 to just get ONE per OP request.. see working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/656d8/41)

```
SELECT
    mt.id, 
    mt.post_id, 
    mt.title
FROM (
  SELECT
  DISTINCT mt1.post_id AS my_post_id,
     (
       SELECT
         tttt.id AS m_id
       FROM myTable tttt
       WHERE tttt.post_id = my_post_id
       ORDER BY rand()
       LIMIT 1
     ) AS t
  FROM myTable mt1
  GROUP BY mt1.post_id
) AS tt
JOIN myTable mt ON mt.id = t
GROUP BY mt.post_id
```

Comment: To clarify, it needs to return 1 random for each `post_id`, not just 1 total

Comment: that should be what youre looking for

Comment: is it possible to combine the WHERE and use IN()? There will be many post_ids, possibly 20. That might be quite a long query then

Comment: building a sql fiddle one sec

Comment: Thats awesome! Before I give it a go, in the fiddle if you refresh enough it will return just one row.

Comment: give it a go in your thing.. the fiddle has been buggy today for some reason.. that query shouldn't be messing up like that... like half the time i get errors saying sql fiddle can't connect to its resource or something weird like that

Comment: ah ok awesome. will check

Comment: oh i know why its returning 1... because the rand() gets the same id sometimes.. let me fiddle with it a bit

Comment: ok i just fixed it. try using the updated query --- i also updated the sql fiddle

Comment: awesome! that seems to work a lot better :) one thing left, not sure if you removed it on purpose, but the IN(1,2,3). I imagine that is better for efficiency?

Comment: yes IN is very slow and i pruposely removed it because it wouldn't work for what you want to do (it would basically get all of the records that have those post_id's instead of one).. and this does exactly what you want.. basically you are getting a random ID for each POST_ID and then selecting all of the stuff from that random ID. so it will get 1 for each POST_ID

Comment: i updated the query again so that the results are just the ID, POST_ID and TITLE since that was what you originally had. let me know if there is anything else you want!

Comment: anytime.. feel free to let me know if you need help with future sql stuff and i'd be happy to help :)

Comment: oh.. i do have one minor question. I take it this is going to get every single record. Is there a good way other than IN() to specify? I only need 10 `post_ids` at a time, and its possible I will have hundreds of `post_ids` total, so it might really add up.

Comment: yea thats simple, so what you can do is this.. where you get the `DISTINCT post_id` -- in that select you have `FROM myTable mt1 GROUP BY mt1.post_id` you would add the WHERE inside there to limit the number of results... if you are going to use multiples for the scope of your project you can do `IN()` if you want or `WHERE post_id = 1234 AND post_id = 2345 AND post_id = 3456`.... etc. IN() would be preferable if you are going to do more than 4 just for readability

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY RAND()` is what you want.

```
SELECT `id`, `post_id`, `title`
FROM `headlines`
WHERE `post_id` IN(9480,9476)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: To clarify, it needs to return 1 random for each `post_id`, not just 1 total